# Is there a way to recover alias key password having the keystore file, keystore password and previous signed apks?

Tags: android, google-play, android-keystore, in-app-update

I need to update my app and I have keystore fil, keystore password, alias name, previous signed apk but forgot the alias key password. Am I screwed ?

Note: I am not using Android Studio to generate apks so there is no logs to check.

I cannot try the bruteforce tool out there because I have no clue what the password might be.

I know that google says that I had to backup my keys and stuff otherwise, I won't be able to make updates and bla bla so please no need to remind me of that. If you know a work around or if anyone has an experience with contacting google to solve the problem, I am all ears.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/keystore-password-recovery

Answer (score 0):

### Because you have forgotten your key password and there are no logs, your key is lost.

No password can be recovered. There is no password reset tool.

And, because your key is lost, you cannot update your app on Google Play anymore. ([docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing))

> Warning: Keep your keystore and private key in a safe and secure place, and ensure that you have secure backups of them. If you publish an app to Google Play and then lose the key with which you signed your app, you will not be able to publish any updates to your app, since you must always sign all versions of your app with the same key.

Answer (score 0):

Contact Google support was the way to go. First, they will verify that is the request initiator is the owner of the app (So you have to be signed in with the google account that owns the app). Then, they reply with some instructions to generate a new keystore and export it in a specific format. After sending them the generated file, they will register it to the upload certificate and send a confirmation.